# Customize "New Work Item" dashboard extension

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

Is there a possibility to take the source code of the "New Work Item" dashboard widget and extend/adapt it to its' own needs? I would not want to re-develop it from scratch.

Thank you, Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to take the source code of the "New Work Item"
>   dashboard widget and extend/adapt it to its' own needs?

Sorry but what you want is not supported.

For now only the pipeline tasks are open-source in [github/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks). And as I know the `New Work Item` widget is not open-source, so it's impossible to take the source code online. I'm afraid you have to develop it on your own. Related document see [Add a dashboard widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops).

And if you do want the source code of the microsoft dashboards widgets to be open-source. You can suggest a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) in our User Voice forum and share the link here. Members who interested in it would vote for you. Hope all above helps :)

Comment: Made the following feature request - hope this also concerns other people.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/960732/make-new-work-item-dashboard-extension-open-source.html